# Footer blank space

Tags: html, css, blogger

I've got this issue with blank space at the bottom of [my blog](http://blog.chobots.pro/):

[image: Screenshot of blank space in footer]

I don't know how to fix it. Can anybody help me?

[Here is the code for the full template](http://justpaste.it/chotemplate), and my footer CSS is below:

```
#footer-wrapper {
margin: 0;
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 9px;
padding-left: 0;
font-size: 85%;
color: #666666;
padding:35px 20px;
}
```

Comment: What is this? Pls post a fiddle to explain your issue.

Comment: Post the HTML as well as the CSS. There could be other elements making the space or inline styles

Comment: bottom: 0; might be? but I think there is issue with some other div u have there...

Comment: there is extra space at the buttom of the page..check the picture i posted.

Comment: http://blog.chobots.pro (ignore the htaccess password requirment-click cancel..it should work)

Comment: the full template code is there: http://justpaste.it/chotemplate

Comment: It would be far better to put your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: No gap here with Chrome.

Comment: By the way, `padding:35px 20px;` to a footer gives you 70px heigh element, at least.

Comment: I don't see any gap in firefox.

Comment: Post only the **relevant** code in a **Fiddle** - http://jsfiddle.net/ , we don't want to debug your entire site. The login box makes it extremely annoying and hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

You have not installed Google Ads correctly, the last call to

```
<script src='http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
```

is adding a HTML element `ins` that is actually an IFrame making your footer higher by `155px`:

[image]

you can hide that with

```
<style type="text/css">
ins {
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

or you can solve Google Ads.

Comment: where should I add the ins {
    display: none !important;
}    ?

Comment: no..i mean..the location..body/head?

Comment: it doesn't matter, the browser will still parse that css rule.

Comment: omg .. add it as a style rule: `<style type="text/css">ins { display: none !important; }</style>`

Answer (score 0):

Check this if it works:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #666666;
}
```

Or more shorter:

```
#footer-wrapper {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #666666;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```